# how to compare json value passed as sp parameter to json value stored in mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, json, stored-procedures

here is MySQL sp:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `records_del_record`(in p_record json)
BEGIN
select p_record;
    update records set rec_status = 1 where recordObj = p_record;
END
```

`recordObj` is of type `json` in `records` table of database

here is how I am invoking query:

```
dbCon.query(`CALL records_del_record(?)`,[[JSON.stringify(record)]], (err, results) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err)
                    reject()
                } else {
                    console.log(results[0][0].p_record)
                    console.log(results[1])
                    resolve()
                }
            })
```

output :

```
{   from: 'first',   recTime: '2022-08-31 19:12:56.000000',   'next visit': '',   prescription: 'Mobile 2' } ResultSetHeader {   fieldCount: 0,   affectedRows: 0,   insertId: 0,   info: '',   serverStatus: 34,   warningStatus: 0 }
```

when sp is executed it doesn't change any rows...
I suspect there is mismatch of type while comparing p_record and recordObj.

any help is appreciated...

Comment: That isn't valid JSON. I suspect you're passing a string which contains double-quotes and therefore is interpreted as a single JSON string.

Comment: well I tried to look what values are passed to stored procedure using select statement and I think everything is fine. There is no double-quotes around the value of `p_record`

Comment: Try putting it in `CAST(p_record AS JSON)` in the stored procedure. If it's not valid JSON, you'll get an error.

Comment: not getting any error...):

Comment: Okay, then I think the string you show as the result is not what is sent to MySQL.

Comment: It is ! as you can see I am doing console.log(...) in 6th and 7th line in .query method's callback

Comment: What does `SELECT VERSION();` report?